# Springboot with Websphere MQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I'm trying to move an application based on Java/EJB to Springboot. The current application is deployed in a websphere server where we have all the queues. What I want to do is to have a springboot app that consumes the queues from a MQ server that is in another host. In order to do that, I started with this article https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/

My doubt is... when I used to access queues from the app the WSA, I use jndi, but now in springboot when I define the listeners I do this

```
@JmsListener(destination = "queueNameHere", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) {

}
```

Where queueNameHere is suppose to be the jndi? I'm not sure about this or what is expecting "destination" in this case.

Any idea on this?

Comment: No, it's not a JNDI name. This should be the queue name.

Comment: when I put the queue name it says it doesn't exists but it does

Comment: May be it expects a JMS queue. Try creating a JMS queue and add its name here in the code.